# How Can I Save my Header File in the standard gallery of header files (or whatever it's called)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, header-files, primes

So I do a lot of programming dealing in math, and I really hate having to write algorithms to find lists of prime numbers as well as check if numbers are prime, over and over again.

Now I want to make this file once, call it 'primes.h', and store it so that at any point I can just open up a program and just `#include <primes>` So what do I do with this header file? Also, what do I do with the 'primes.cpp' that goes along with it?

Thanks,

Live2Code

Comment: You may want to create a library (either static or DLL) and put that in a well-known location. Also place the header files there, and then simply tell the compiler what that location is (somewhere in project settings for VS).

Answer (score 0):

Create a library, add the directory of the library and the header file to "path".
the header file do not have to have a ".h" extension. This is the vecotr file for stl:

```
#ifndef __SGI_STL_VECTOR
#define __SGI_STL_VECTOR

#include <stl_range_errors.h>
#include <stl_algobase.h>
#include <stl_alloc.h>
#include <stl_construct.h>
#include <stl_uninitialized.h>
#include <stl_vector.h>
#include <stl_bvector.h>

#endif /* __SGI_STL_VECTOR */
```

you can just create a header file named as "prime" and

```
#include <primes>
```

Comment: System path is not used for headerfile lookups. There may be a `%INCLUDE_PATH%` or some such environment variable, but it's almost certainly a bad idea to use that.

Answer (score 0):

The names like `<primes>` are reserved for the standard library functionality, you should not use that sort of name - unless you convince the standards committee to include your code into the standard, that is.

You can certainly store a `primes.h` in a "central place where every project can get to it" - I wouldn't put them in with the header files that come with your compiler, because that means you have copy a new set when you switch to Visual Studio 2013 or some such. Instead, add a new `include directory` to your project, which points at your include directory. It's not very difficult to do, and it's a "once per project" thing.

Comment: Names like `my_primes` and `my_math_lib` are common to avoid naming clashes.